# jQuery consuming JSON WCF

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, json

I have a WCF service with 3 string arguments. Calling this with jQuery and JSON does reach my method but only 1 of the arguments contain a value - the others are received null, even though they are passed. Any thoughts why?

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public string Save(string site, string title, string contentType)
    {
        // method...
    }
```

JS:

```
                    $.ajax(
                      {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Service.svc/Save",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: "{\"title\": \"title...\", \"site\": \"site...\", \"contentType\": \"contentType...\"}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function(data) {
                        },
                        error: function() {
                          alert("Sorry, an error has occured");
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: Have you tried correcting the ordering of parameters? Your service method accepts params in the order site, title and contentType but you are sending it in the order title,site and contentType. Not sure if this will solve it but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that. The order of params doesn't change the outcome. Title is the only argument whose value is received.

Comment: Works when I tried it. I created a WCF service application in VS2010 and my JQuery version is 1.5.1. Here is a hunch: rename the site and contentType names.

Comment: Do you encode your parameters on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm.

The argument name for those two missing arguments was different in the ServiceContract to the service. I was using the argument name that was in the service, not the one in the ServiceContract. Stupid.

Thanks for the replies guys.